# PL/SQL Relational operator <> , != Syntax issue

Tags: sql, database, oracle, syntax

I am trying below code in pl/sql program.
 I didn't get my code running through any of the below condition, it just skips all the 'if' conditions.

Code snap :---

```
IF(null != 'C') THEN 
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('1');
 END IF;

 IF(Trim('') <> 'C') THEN 
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('2');
 END IF;

 IF(Trim('') != 'C') THEN 
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('3');
 END IF;
```

Comment: `IF('C' IS NULL) THEN `. `NULL` cannot be used with any relational operator, though it is syntactically valid. Also `''` is `NULL`

Comment: By "IF(NULL != 'C')" Are you trying to check if 'C' is null? I think it should be IF('C' IS NOT NULL) but it will never return true as 'C' is definitely not going to be null.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar "`''` is `NULL`" - hmm?

Comment: `''` is treated as null by Oracle, but not by other dbms's

Comment: <> is the sql standard; != is included by vendors but not part of the standard (so I believe)

Answer (score 3):

Unlike in other databases, in Oracle an empty string (`''`) is actually the same as `NULL`, so `Trim('')` is `NULL` too. Therefor, all three if statements actually have the same condition.

**Normal comparison operators don't work for null**

The normal comparison operators like `=`, `<>` and `!=` don't work for `NULL`, so they also don't work for `''` either. 
By *don't work* I mean, they always return `false`, regardless of the other operand. Every comparison with `NULL` will result in `false`, so `X = null` and `X != null` are both false. Sounds like quantum physics, doesn't it? :) 
This rule does apply to all databases, by the way.

**IS and IS NOT for NULL**

You can use the special `is` and `is not` operators for null, so the following two ifs are semantically the same (in Oracle):

```
if C is not null then

if C is not '' then
```

But this one is wrong:

```
if C != '' then
```

Because it actually means the following, and always returns false:

```
if C != null then
```

**Most string functions return NULL as well for NULL input**

This can be a huge nuisance, since even `length('')` returns `null` instead of `0`: Easy to make a mistake there.

```
select length('') from dual -- Returns NULL
```

Extra tricky, because a 'normal' comparison with 0 returns false. So the following (accidentally) works

```
select 
  case when length(StringField) > 0 then
    'string is not empty'
  else
    'string is empty'
  end
from dual
```

But this one does not:

```
select 
  case when length(StringField) = 0 then
    'string is empty'
  else
    'string is not empty'
  end
from dual
```

Comment: Is this the same for all versions of oracle?

Comment: it is for 8, 9, 10 and 11 (as far as I can recall) haven't played with 12 as yet

Comment: Second that. And I don't think this will change. It's one of the design decisions of Oracle. Everything about `NULL` in this answer applies to all databases, by the way. The only thing that applies to just Oracle (and some others) is that `''` behaves the same as `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle NULL cannot be compared with a value
hence you can use the function NVL(x,y) in which  if x has value the function returns x and if x is null it returns y

```
IF (NVL(NULL,'D') != 'C')
THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('1');
END IF;

IF(NVL(Trim(''),'D') <> 'C') THEN 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('2');
END IF;

IF(NVL(Trim(''),'D') != 'C') THEN 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('3');
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me every condition from your question means the same as:

```
IF('C' is not null) THEN  
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('1');
 END IF;
```

This is properly way to compare your value with `NULL`

`Trim('')` means null, so this condition isn't correct

```
Trim('') <> 'C'
Trim('') != 'C'
```

and this one isn't correct too

```
null != 'C'
```